# How did strange git artifacts get into my commited source code?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I recently committed software changes to my gitHub repo. I had a local repo on computer A and then went to do some work in the repo on computer B. I was unable to push my changes done in repo B to my gitHub repo (internet problems) so I simply copied the modified source files and overwrote the relevant source files on computer A with them. On computer A I attempted to push my changes to the gitHub repo and strangely ran into a detached head problem. I don't know enough to understand why this happened as I'm the only contributor to the repo, but in any case I added all my local files and continued the rebase to fix the problem. All was good an dandy, but today I looked at my source files and found strange git artfacts spread around my source code:
    #include "TIM3.h"

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
#define PRESCALAR 1000

void TIM3_Init(uint32_t freq)
{
    uint32_t periodValue;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef  TIM_TimeBaseStructure;
=======
#define PRESCALAR 42000

/*Timer initializer*/
void TIM3_Init(uint32_t freq)
{   
    uint32_t periodValue;   //Holds the period value
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef  TIM_TimeBaseStructure; //Creating the timer initializing strucure
>>>>>>> lab3 complete and some report

    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;    //Creating the NVIC initializing structure
```

the "<<<<<<< HEAD", the "=========" and the ">>>>>>> lab3 complete and some report" weren't originally in my source code. the "lab3 complete and some report" is the commit comment I made for the most recent commit.

How/Why did this happen?

Comment: You had a merge conflict. It needs to be resolved.

Comment: You had a detached HEAD problem because you had run some commands that changed your HEAD to a detached one. Also, I thought rebase is a sufficiently advanced tool that implies knowing how to resolve merge conflicts.

Comment: I used the gitHub for windows GUI tool and at no point used the command-line until I had to fix the detached head. Can the gitHub windows program call those commands that detach head? It's a very simplistic interface: it basically only lets you commit/push and clone.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this in our commits. 
This is how it happened to us (well I assume :)

1. You merge a branch, and you get a conflict and it goes into MERGING state (visible in the git bash behind your branch name)
2. You open git gui
3. you click on the icon in front of the file (which is actually in conflict on the MERGING branch) in the top right list to stage your file
4. in your git gui you commit, or from the git-bash after closing git-gui.

--> this commit gets pushed to origin, and you have and issue!
We found all our issues because of build issues so we were lucky ;)